# Minecraft Map Making

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

When making maps with mods installed, do the people playing it need the mods used to make the map in order to play it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** and **No**, it depends whether or not the mod changes the way the map is played and if it adds anything additional that is not in Vanilla.

This, hopefully, will clear this out:

---

Mods like "Too Many Items" ("TMI"), Optifine and WorldEdit just to name a few add something to the game, extra inventories, textures, and you do **not** need the players to download it to play the map. So for example if you create a map with Optifine installed you do not need the players on a server or on single player to have Optifine installed. (Proving @Rooki_Boi's answer correct).

Unlike mods like Crash mod, PixelMon, Manite which add new blocks, items, mobs etc. In which if you create a world and share it without listing the mods will corrupt it when opening and or will crash. (Proving @ArceusMaster0493's answer correct).

---

So it depends on which mod you have installed or are thinking of building with. I hope this does help you in your consideration.

*(My answer is constructed on both @Rooki_Boi and @ArceusMaster0493 answers, as they both are  partially correct.)*

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't. As long as the mods/plugins used to make the map are uninstalled, before
playing the game. For example, if Optifine was used to make the map, but uninstalled when the map was done, the players of the map wouldn't need to install that mod to play, however, if the mod
is NOT uninstalled, the game will crash as they enter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All players playing on the map have to use the mod to play, or else mods will not be functional. Take crash mod for example. You can do `/crash` and a player will disconnect and crash after being shown a random picture (like a hotdog, goat, pug, etc.) But if the player specified to be crashed does not have the mod installed, then `/crash` will not function and he/she will not crash.